# How can I make Windows 7 more touch-friendly?

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

Is there any software that I can install to make my experience on a Windows 7 tablet a bit better?

Here are some features I'd like to have:

- automatically show virtual keyboard when i select a text zone, and
  automatically resize the window so it will be visible with the keyboard out
- iPad-like copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link you should find interesting. This guy has a list of free tools you can install and customize to make your Windows 7 pc more touch friendly. He even has a short demo video showing his own system customized.

http://windows7tablet.blogspot.com/2011/05/windows-7-touch-optimizations.html

Comment: interesting, he don't do as expected but it may helps i ll give it a try